# Nuget and Git Integration

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have a solution with several projects in Visual Studio 2013. I use Git.
Now, each project has its own packages folder.
I have two questions that I hope you can help me.
Do you recommend me to commit these folders?

For use nuget in a solution, which is the best scenario MSBuild-based package restore or Automatic package restore?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The advised way of working is to let NuGet recreate the `packages` folder during builds. It is not required, nor advisable to add the binaries to source control, when you have access to the package repository containing your packages.

You could at most commit the `repositories.config` from the packages folder. Al the package content can be retrieved during build. You can leave the repositories.config as a hint for the build process, and it will cost little to add this file to source control.

There is [a complete explanation here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages):

> The original NuGet workflow has been to commit the Packages folder
>   into source control. The reasoning is that it matches what developers
>   typically do when they don't have NuGet: they create a Lib or
>   ExternalDependencies folder, dump binaries into there and commit them
>   to source control to allow others to build.
>
> While this has worked fine for some users, we have also heard from
>   many that committing packages into source control is not what they
>   want to do. When using a DVCS like Mercurial or Git, committing
>   binaries can grow the repository size like crazy over time, making
>   cloning more and more painful. In fact, this has been one of the top
>   requests on NuGet our issue tracker.
>
> The good news is that NuGet now offers a workflow which goes a long
>   way to solving this problem, and is really easy to set up. Here is the
>   way to do it:
>
> Enabling Package Restore During Build Beginning with NuGet 2.0,
>   restoring packages during build requires explicit consent from the
>   user. This must be done on each machine that builds the project.
>
> In Visual Studio, enable "Allow NuGet to download missing packages
>   during build". This setting lives under Options -> Package Manager ->
>   General.
>
> Allow NuGet to download missing packages setting
>
> To enable package restore for build servers without Visual Studio
>   installed, you can also set the environment variable
>   EnableNuGetPackageRestore to "true".
>
> Project Setup Let’s assume that you have a solution that is either
>   already using NuGet, or planning to use it, and that you want to set
>   up the no-commit workflow.
>
> Right click on the Solution node in Solution Explorer and select
>   Enable NuGet Package Restore.
>
> Enable NuGet Package Restore Context Menu item
>
> That's it! You're all set.
>
> Details So what exactly did that do? It added a solution folder named
>   .nuget containing NuGet.exe and a NuGet.targets MsBuild file. More
>   specifically, it downloaded and extracted two NuGet packages:
>   NuGet.Commandline for NuGet.exe and NuGet.Build for NuGet.targets. It
>   also changed every project in the solution to import the NuGet.targets
>   MsBuild task.
>
> New Solution folder with package restore files
>
> Finally, it added a NuGet.config file with the following XML:
>
> The disableSourceControlIntegration
>   setting instructs version control systems like TFS to not add the
>   NuGet packages folder to the pending check-ins list.
>
> With this in place, any time a project is compiled, the build task
>   will look at each project's packages.config file and for each package
>   listed, ensure that the corresponding package exists within the
>   packages folder. For any missing package, the build task will download
>   and unpack the package.

Comment: Visual Studio will restore the packages/repositories.config file when the packages are restored. Also the MSBuild based package restore which you enable by selecting `Enable NuGet Package Restore` has been deprecated by the NuGet team. With recent versions of NuGet in Visual Studio the NuGet packages are restored just before the build is run.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably download [the official recommended Visual Studio .gitignore file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore) and put it in the root of your repository. From there, most git tools will automatically detect this file and use it to ignore the proper files and folders, including but not limited to nuget package folders.